# How to not allow a sub-class method to be defined in PHP

Tags: php, class, methods

How can I prevent the `something` method below to be created in the foo class ?

```
class fooBase{

  public function something(){

  }
}

class foo extends fooBase{

  public function __construct(){
    echo $this->something(); // <- should be the parent class method
  }

  public function something(){ 
    // this method should not be allowed to be created
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `final` keyword  (like in Java etc):

```php
class fooBase{

  final public function something(){

  }
}

class foo extends fooBase{

  public function __construct(){
    echo $this->something(); // <- should be the parent class method
  }

  public function something(){ 
    // this method should not be allowed to be created
  }
}
```

See [PHP Final keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php). Note that `foo` will still have a method `something`, but `something` will only come from `fooBase` and `foo` can't override it.

Comment: can `__construct` methods be final too (if fooBase had one)?

Comment: Yes, __construct can be final. If you say it is final in the parent class, you cannot have one in the child.

Comment: Indeed, as SamT says, you can make `__construct` final.

Answer (score 2):

Use the final keyword.

In your parent:

```
final public function something()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [final](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) to prevent base methods being overwritten.

```
class fooBase{

  final public function something(){

  }
}
```